# cannot auto check enum type displayed as radio button

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a table that displays radio button options in a table one for the current result and the other for the next session status. I am able to display the radio buttons which are of type enum in the table but cannot auto check it based on database content. I have a method that selects only the currentResult field from the database which is working as expected but cannot set current result(studentPromo.setCurrentResult()) to the results from the database. Aside from that, I have also tried something like th:checked="${studSS == studPromo.currentResult}" in the view which I get  Cannot compare instances of class com.sch.common.entity.CurrentResult and class com.sch.common.entity.CurrentResult error. I don't know what I am missing. Below is the code sample

enum class for current results and next session status

```
public enum CurrentResult {
Pass,Fail
```

}

```
public enum NextSessionStatus {
Continue, Leave
```

}

entity class for student promotion

```
public class StudentPromotion extends IdBaseEntity{

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
Student student;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
CurrentResult currentResult;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
NextSessionStatus nextSessionStatus;

//setter and getter omitted
```

}

repository interface

```
@Repository
```

public interface StudentPromotionRepository extends CrudRepository<StudentPromotion, Integer>{

```
@Query("SELECT currentResult FROM StudentPromotion")
public List<CurrentResult> findByCurrentResult();;
```

}

service class

```
@Service
```

public class StudentPromotionService {

```
@Autowired StudentPromotionRepository studentPromoRepo;

//service method to display list of students
public List<StudentPromotion> displayStudents() {
    return (List<StudentPromotion>) studentPromoRepo.findAll();
}

//method that find student currentResult
public List<CurrentResult> findCurrentResults() {
    return studentPromoRepo.findByCurrentResult();
}
```

}

controller class

```
@Controller
```

public class StudentPromotionController {

```
@Autowired StudentPromotionService studentPromoService;

@GetMapping("/students/promotion")
public String listStudentPromotion(@ModelAttribute("studentPromo") StudentPromotion studentPromo, Model model) {
    
    List<StudentPromotion> stuList = studentPromoService.displayStudents();
    
    List<CurrentResult> currentResultFromDB = studentPromoService.findCurrentResults();
    studentPromo.setCurrentResult();    
    System.out.println("enum values " + currentResultFromDB);
    model.addAttribute("listAllStudents", stuList);
    model.addAttribute("currentResultFromDB", currentResultFromDB);
    
    return "students/student_promotion";
}
```

}

thymeleaf section that display the table with the radio buttons

```html
<div>
            <form action="#" method="post" th:object="${studentPromo}">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive-sm align-middle" id="tableRefresh">
                <thead class="text-center">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Admission No</th>
                        <th scope="col">Student Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Father Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Date of Birth</th>
                        <th scope="col">Current Result</th>
                        <th scope="col">Next Session Status</th>
                    
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="studPromo : ${listAllStudents}" >
                        <td>[[${studPromo.student.admissionNumber}]]</td>
                        <td>[[${studPromo.student.fullName}]]</td>
                        <td>[[${studPromo.student.parentGuardian.fatherName}]]</td>
                        <td>[[${#dates.format(studPromo.student.dob, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}]] </td>
                        <td >
                            <div class="d-flex">
                                <div  th:each="studCR : ${T(com.sch.common.entity.CurrentResults).values()}">
                                    <input type="radio"  th:field="*{currentResult}" th:value="${studCR}" class="form-check-input" 
                                    >
                                    <label class="form-check-label me-2" >[[${studCR}]]</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            <div class="d-flex">
                                <div  th:each="studSS : ${T(com.sch.common.entity.MyEnum.NextSessionStatus).values()}">
                                    <input type="radio"  th:field="*{nextSessionStatus}" th:value="${studSS}" class="form-check-input"  >
                                    <label class="form-check-label me-2">[[${studSS}]]</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </form> 
        </div>
```

picture of the table
[image: picture of the table]

pictures of the database

[image: picture of database]